# How skip to next line using StreamReader after founding the value that I was looking for?

Tags: c#, azure, streamreader

I am working in a project where I am reading values from a .txt file to check if the data I am fetching from the database has at least one value equal to the .txt file.

Example:

.txt file content

22,
23,
24,
25

'23' from .txt file should have 4 results from the database, what I want to do is after finding if has 1 result go to the next line in this case 23.

I try to create a model with a bool to compare if has been added but still not working, added to a hashset and no result.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void Fetch()
    {

        List <CList> itemList = new List<CList>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("numberOfItems.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] itemsC = line.Split(",");                    

             //Logic here: check if itemC has one result from container, skip to the next line in numberOfItems.txt

                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `.txt` file really have more than one line? It seems you really have just one line of comma delimited values. You'll need to iterate your `itemsC` array. If I am reading this correctly. Your exact question isn't really clear.

Comment: @ScottWelker my .txt has 10 lines, I want to check if the value getting from .txt is equal to the data from the database ill added to a list and go to the next line, no adding more than one item.

Comment: If you file has only 10 lines, honestly, skip the `StreamReader` and just use `File.ReadAllLines` to get the whole thing into a `string[]`. Then skipping a line is as easy as reading the next element in the array.

Comment: The [continue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-continue-statement/#:~:text=In%20C%23%2C%20the%20continue%20statement,next%20iteration%20of%20the%20loop.) statement seems to be the answer to your question but I don't really think that is what you intended to ask.

Comment: When using `ReadLine` on a `StreamReader`, the reader starts at the current position and reads until it sees a line end, and then hands back the line of text as a string.  Lines may be long, or they may be empty, so there's no magic "skip to the next line".  What you want to do is that if you decide to skip the next line, you set a flag saying `ignoreNextLine`.  When the flag is set, you read the next line but you don't process it (the only processing you do is to clear the `ignoreNextLine` flag).

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the StreamReader is reading every thing as a string, therefore you could use a loop to ignore everything until you hit a `\n` (newline) character, or jut use `System.Linq.Enumerable.SkipWhile()` to skip every character until you find a nwline character.